# Why isn't my if statement working? python/pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            keys_pressed_p2 += 1
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0] - 1][5] == "a"):
        key_right = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0] - 1][5] == "b"):
        key_right = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0] - 1][5] == "c"):
        key_right = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0] - 1][5] == "d"):
        key_right = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        keys_pressed += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0] - 1][5] == "a"):
        arrow_key_right = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0] - 1][5] == "b"):
        arrow_key_right = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0] - 1][5] == "c"):
        arrow_key_right = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and (General_knowledge[general_knowlege_questions[0]- 1][5] == "d"):
        arrow_key_right = 1


    if (key_right == 1) and (rect_width > 0) and (keys_pressed == 1):
        key_right = 0
        keys_pressed = 0
        player_1_score = rect_width / 30
        player_1_score = round(player_1_score, 0)
        print(player_1_score)

    if (arrow_key_right == 1) and (rect_width > 0) and (keys_pressed_p2 == 1):
        arrow_key_right = 0
        keys_pressed_p2 = 0
        player_2_score = rect_width / 30
        player_2_score = round(player_2_score, 0)
        print(player_2_score)
```

my code works for when w,a,s,d keys are pressed along with the space bar, however, the last if black at the very bottom doesn't work. I don't understand this as both are the same except for the fact that the latter uses mouse click instead of the space bar. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the difference `key_right` and `arrow_key_right`? This is also a bit unclear. I'm not sure what is happening and what is giving you problems exactly. Can you try to provide a clearer [mcve]?

Comment: key_right and arrow_key_right are variables to distinguish between player 1 and player 2. player one has w, a, s d as their controls. If they press the correct option then key_right becomes 1, which then allows the next if-block to activate. The same goes for arrow_key_right and player 2. Also keys_pressed is a variable to make sure that they only press the space bar or click once, so only one answer from the quiz gets selected rather than multiple. Hope that clears things up!

Answer (score 0):

I assume line 5 makes problem:

```
keys_pressed_p2 += 1
```

It seems the operator should be `=` instead of `+=`.

Your code would also work if the mentioned `if` statement was `...and keys_pressed_p2:` instead of `...and (keys_pressed_p2 == 1):` because values other than 0 are considered to be `True`.

Good luck!